# Percentage of values above the 99th percentile

Tags: r

How can I compute the sum of values that is above the 99th percentile. And then divide it by the total values to get the percentage of values above the 99th percentile.
For example dataset mtcars

```
> summary(mtcars$hp)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   52.0    96.5   123.0   146.7   180.0   335.0 

> quantile(mtcars$hp, 0.99)
   99% 
312.99 

> sum(mtcars$hp)
[1] 4694
```

So from here it's like summing up all the values that is greater than 312.99 and then divide it by 4694.

Comment: Quick question what should I add on your code to make it a percentage with 1 decimal places. e.g 7.1%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get the a vector indicating if a value is above the 99th percentile with the condition `mtcars$hp > quantile(mtcars$hp, 0.99)`, which can be used to subset `mtcars$hp` which you can sum up.

```
sum(mtcars$hp[mtcars$hp > quantile(mtcars$hp, 0.99)]) / sum(mtcars$hp)
#[1] 0.0713677
```

To make it a percentage with 1 decimal places multiply with 100 and use `round` like:

```
round(sum(mtcars$hp[mtcars$hp>quantile(mtcars$hp, 0.99)])/sum(mtcars$hp)*100,1)
#[1] 7.1
```